# add foreign key in rdbms oracle server of sql

Tags: sql, oracle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtQWJ.png)
please give the query for the given relational model. this is the error I am getting while adding foreign keys.
[this is the error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xFzY.png)

I think foreign key is not working properly in my code

Comment: Actually remove `foreign key` altogether.

Comment: Please copy the bad command in text form, so we can tweak it.

Comment: Don't spam tags. Oracle != MySQL.

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode